# Bitbake meta-toolchain-qt5: UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: qt5, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

Bit of a strange one here, this exact configuration used to build just fine, but now fails.  I have no custom bbappends in my qt5 layers, so it should really just be a vanilla build from meta-qt5.

Failure looks like this:

```
$ bitbake meta-toolchain-qt5
NOTE: Started PRServer with DBfile: /media/parallels/build/cache/prserv.sqlite3, IP: 127.0.0.1, PORT: 38360, PID: 18679
Loading cache: 100% |###################################################################################################################################################| ETA:  00:00:00
Loaded 2898 entries from dependency cache.
Parsing recipes: 100% |#################################################################################################################################################| Time: 00:00:01
Parsing of 2362 .bb files complete (2359 cached, 3 parsed). 2900 targets, 156 skipped, 9 masked, 0 errors.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.26.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "Ubuntu-14.04"
TARGET_SYS        = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE           = "overo"
DISTRO            = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "1.8"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "arm armv7a vfp neon callconvention-hard cortexa8"
TARGET_FPU        = "vfp-neon"
meta              
meta-yocto        = "(nobranch):83aa565d93aacae484976562ef1ae8dbbb6b2bc0"
meta-gnome        
meta-oe           
meta-xfce         
meta-systemd      
meta-networking   
meta-multimedia   
meta-python       = "(nobranch):10d3c8f85280a0bf867a8e4f84bcda81c290d28e"
meta-gumstix      = "(nobranch):68e4b5771aef2d11fcf04bb8759fecd409de1ac3"
meta-gumstix-extras = "(nobranch):0ee78d47ff3082000e9e087b1ec0d56df13457d9"
meta-bluechiip    = "HHR-STREAM4:a60b5fb37479e2ff1348ab100c0f3735713a730c"
meta-ros          = "(nobranch):d465a23c0a96e651419d46b29ab7c0c3663da314"
meta-ti           = "(nobranch):03cb3ff15f3b8535ca409ce682f44ec1b81da0c3"
meta-java         = "(nobranch):66c97ae7461f4c1a13917131787bb76dc34e6b6f"
meta-qt5          = "(nobranch):90919b9d86988e7da01fa2c0a07246b5b5600a5d"

NOTE: Preparing RunQueue
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: Unable to install packages. Command '/media/parallels/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/smart --quiet --data-dir=/media/parallels/build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/sdk/image/opt/poky/1.8/sysroots/cortexa8hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/var/lib/smart install -y packagegroup-core-standalone-sdk-target-dbg@all packagegroup-core-standalone-sdk-target@all packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target@all' returned 1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/parallels/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smart/backends/rpm/pm.py", line 358, in __call__
    self._process_rpmout()
  File "/media/parallels/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smart/backends/rpm/pm.py", line 343, in _process_rpmout
    output = self.rpmout.read()
  File "/media/parallels/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 474, in read
    newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4948: ordinal not in range(128)

ERROR: Function failed: do_populate_sdk
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /media/parallels/build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_populate_sdk.18850
ERROR: Task 7 (/home/parallels/yocto/poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/meta/meta-toolchain-qt5.bb, do_populate_sdk) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 4705 tasks of which 4704 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
No currently running tasks (4704 of 4706)
```

(A bit more verbosity on the exact point of failure...)

```
$ bitbake -v -c populate_sdk meta-toolchain-qt5
<snip>
NOTE: Executing '/media/parallels/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/createrepo --dbpath /media/parallels/build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/rpmdb/cortexa8hf_vfp_neon --update -q /media/parallels/build/tmp/deploy/rpm/cortexa8hf_vfp_neon' ...
NOTE: Executing '/media/parallels/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/createrepo --dbpath /media/parallels/build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/rpmdb/x86_64_nativesdk --update -q /media/parallels/build/tmp/deploy/rpm/x86_64_nativesdk' ...
NOTE: Installing the following packages: packagegroup-core-standalone-sdk-target-dbg packagegroup-core-standalone-sdk-target packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target
NOTE: to be installed: packagegroup-core-standalone-sdk-target-dbg@all packagegroup-core-standalone-sdk-target@all packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target@all
NOTE: /media/parallels/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/smart --quiet --data-dir=/media/parallels/build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/sdk/image/opt/poky/1.8/sysroots/cortexa8hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/var/lib/smart install -y packagegroup-core-standalone-sdk-target-dbg@all packagegroup-core-standalone-sdk-target@all packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target@all
ERROR: Unable to install packages. Command '/media/parallels/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/smart --quiet --data-dir=/media/parallels/build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/sdk/image/opt/poky/1.8/sysroots/cortexa8hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/var/lib/smart install -y packagegroup-core-standalone-sdk-target-dbg@all packagegroup-core-standalone-sdk-target@all packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target@all' returned 1:
Output from udev-cache-182-r9.0.0@cortexa8hf_vfp_neon:
 Removing any system startup links for udev-cache ...
 Adding system startup for /media/parallels/build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/sdk/image/opt/poky/1.8/sysroots/cortexa8hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/etc/init.d/udev-cache.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/parallels/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smart/backends/rpm/pm.py", line 358, in __call__
    self._process_rpmout()
  File "/media/parallels/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smart/backends/rpm/pm.py", line 343, in _process_rpmout
    output = self.rpmout.read()
  File "/media/parallels/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 474, in read
    newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4948: ordinal not in range(128)

ERROR: Function failed: do_populate_sdk
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /media/parallels/build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_populate_sdk.344
ERROR: Task 6 (/home/parallels/yocto/poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/meta/meta-toolchain-qt5.bb, do_populate_sdk) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 3582 tasks of which 3581 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
```

My reading of this is that the package manager expected only ascii characters in the packages packagegroup-core-standalone-sdk-target-dbg packagegroup-core-standalone-sdk-target & packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target and encountered an out-of-range value (195 / 0xc3).  Presumably smart is expecting the wrong encoding.  If this is correct, how can an alternate encoding be specified for the installation of these packages & how could I determine what the correct encoding should be?

I am a little surprised that this has suddenly become an issue as my build is pointing at exactly the same sources as its previous, working state - it could be something else entirely.  The only other thing that occurs to me is that I did run an apt-get update between the build working and this failure, so it's entirely possible that the version of one of the build tools may have changed.

Any advice on how to proceed would be most gratefully received, please let me know if I can provide any more data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's actually not failing on any package related to meta-qt5, but udev-cache which should come from the udev recipe in oe-core.

If you have built the same sources before without issues I would try forcing a rebuild of the udev package, just to rule out that some file just accidentally got corrupted.

Try `bitbake -c cleansstate udev` and then `bitbake meta-toolchain-qt5` again.

Comment: Good advice, but the build still fails in identical fashion.  I'm pretty sure I deleted my entire build directory previously, but got the same result!

Comment: Have you modified your build host system? Nowadays I almost always build in a docker container using a Ubuntu version from the list of tested distros for the particular Yocto release. Might be something to try out if you think it can be related to host system upgrades. Check out https://github.com/crops/poky-container for ready to use docket images.